# Does PPSX works on any PC or do I have to install something?

Tags: microsoft-office, presentations, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

PPSX presentations created with Office 2010 can be executed on any PC without special requirements or should be something installed on it, like certain version of .NET Framework version X, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPSX files are saved in the Open XML format, which was introduced in Microsoft Office 2007; they may be opened by PowerPoint 2007 or later, or by earlier versions of PowerPoint with the Open XML component installed. Another possibility is to use [Microsoft PowerPoint Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=048dc840-14e1-467d-8dca-19d2a8fd7485).

Comment: I mean PPSX the new format of PPS file (autoexecutable PowerPoint presentation). I think that your answer is related to PPTX

Comment: PPSX stands for PowerPoint Open XML Slide Show, and my answer is still valid for it.

Comment: To clarify Mehper's answer: PPSX is the "presentation" extension, meaning the file will open directly as a slideshow, rather than for editing. The content and file format are identical to a PPSX, it just gets handled differently when opened. Any computer with PowerPoint 2007 or newer, or with the converter for Office 2000/2003, or with PowerPoint Viewer 2007, should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In layman’s terms the answer seems to be YES you need to have something installed. I’ve now wrestled with Ppsx for a day. It doesn’t seem to work anyway, it still opens in edit mode. Think I’ll try a pdf or a gnt.